# Remove-ItemProperty does not seem to work with -LiteralPath

Tags: powershell, registry

I'm trying to remove all values from a registry key. When dealing with the registry in PowerShell, I always pass `LiteralPath`, and it works fine everywhere except for `Remove-ItemProperty`.

This does not work as I expected:
`Remove-ItemProperty -LiteralPath 'HKCU:Delete_all_values' -Name *`

but the regular `-Path` works:
`Remove-ItemProperty -Path 'HKCU:Delete_all_values' -Name *`

Official docs are silent on this matter. Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for. What is the right way to clear a default value for a key? `Clear-ItemProperty` seems to have two problems: 1) it does not handle a case when there is a value named '(default)' (a corner case for sure, but still) and 2) it does not seem to actually set the value to $null, or whatever is null in the Registry terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're really looking for is `Clear-Item` - it'll remove all values but leave the key and any subkeys intact:

```
Clear-Item -LiteralPath HKCU:\Delete_all_values
```

---

#### Why doesn't `-Name *` work with `-LiteralPath`?

Using `-LiteralPath` causes the `*-ItemProperty` provider cmdlets to **suppress *all wildcard expansion*** - including for property names:

```
Get-ItemProperty -Path HKCU:\Delete_all_values -Name *         # returns all properties
Get-ItemProperty -LiteralPath HKCU:\Delete_all_values -Name *  # returns no properties (unless you have one with the literal name *)
```

You will observe the same behavior if you pipe a registry item, as PowerShell will bind the key's full provider path to `-LiteralPath` by default:

```
Get-Item HKCU:\Delete_all_values |Get-ItemProperty -Name *  # returns no properties (unless you have one with the literal name *)
```

Explicitly passing the value names to `-Name` will solve the problem:

```
$targetKey = Get-Item -LiteralPath HKCU:\Delete_all_values

# piping a RegistryKey instance will also cause binding against -LiteralPath
$targetKey |Remove-ItemProperty -Name $targetKey.GetValuesNames()
```

At which point you might as well just use `Clear-Item`